# how to change the value stored in a VLA which is in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following structure im using to encode a PPM file with a message using steganography:

```
typedef struct{
    char code[CODE_LENGTH];
    COMMENT *commentPPM;
    int width, height, max;
    COLOR (*colorValues)[];
} PPM;
```

and the color:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned char red, green, blue;
} COLOR;
```

and method:

```
PPM *encode(char *text, PPM *img){

    //tested
    printf("entered encode\n");

    PPM *newPPM;
    newPPM = duplicate(img);
    printf("duplicated ppm\n");

    int x,y, currentChar, textLength;

    textLength = strlen(text);
    ////

    for(currentChar = x = y = 0; currentChar < textLength; currentChar++){
        printf("the current character is %c\n", *(text+currentChar));
        //between 1 and the width
        x += (rand() % (newPPM->width -1)) + 1; 
        printf("generated %d for x\n",x);
        if(x >= newPPM->width){
            printf("%d is greater than width(%d)\n",x,newPPM->width);
            x -= newPPM->width;
            printf("%d is the new x\n", x);
            y++;
            printf("incremented y to be %d\n", y);
        }
        newPPM->colorValues[y][x].red = text[currentChar]; //error (1)
        printf("changed the value of color[%d][%d].red, to be %d, which is %c\n",y,x, text[currentChar], text[currentChar]);
    }

    return newPPM;
}
```

How do you access for example "red" within the pointer to the 1d array seen at (1)?

Edit: I get the error message:
"error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
   newPPM->colorValues[y][x].red = text[currentChar];"

Edit 2: I'm hearing that I cannot access the elements of colorValues in

```
typedef struct{
    char code[CODE_LENGTH];
    COMMENT *commentPPM;
    int width, height, max;
    COLOR (*colorValues)[];
} PPM;
```

as it hasn't got the width specified so i cant determine the offset. However I this is just a pointer to a flexible array member is getting assigned a type

```
ppmFile->colorValues = getColors(fd, ppmFile->width, ppmFile->height);

COLOR (*getColors(FILE *fd, int width, int height))[]{

    COLOR (*colors)[width] = (COLOR(*)[width]) malloc(sizeof(COLOR[height][width]));

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < width; j++) {        
            fscanf(fd,"%d %d %d", &colors[i][j].red, &colors[i][j].green, &colors[i][j].blue);  
        }
    }

    return colors;
}
```

which has got the width specified. So if I'm understanding correct when I am passing this back to be stored in the struct i am "losing" the offset (width). However When I am in the encrypt method, I have access to the width, height, and current x and y positions, surely there is a way of telling the compiler that this flexible array member has the offset of width,I did do this in the printColors method and it worked fine (see bellow), why cant I tell the compiler that the values stored in newPPM->colorValues have the offset of width?

```
void printColors(int width, int height, COLOR (*colors)[width]){
    int n, j;
    for(n = 0; n < height; n++) {
        for(j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", colors[n][j].red, colors[n][j].green, colors[n][j].blue);  
        }
    }
}
```

is there a way of casting the newPPM->colorValues to tell it to have the offset width? Like I did with colors in printColors

Comment: That's not a VLA, it's a flexible array member. I don't think it can be 2D, can't see how that would work.

Comment: I thought it was a pointer to a 1d array the way I define it is like this: COLOR (*colors)[width] = (COLOR(*)[width]) malloc(sizeof(COLOR[height][width]));

Comment: It's not a flexible array member, it's a pointer to an array of unspecified size. Not fully legal C.

Comment: how do I "specify" the size? I cant force the width to be a fixed value as its depended on what is read in from the file

Comment: An array *is* a fixed-size object (a VLA is still a fixed-size object, but with a dependent type, ignore them for now). As with any dynamically-allocated buffer, you'd access it through a pointer to the element type and use pointer indexing. No array required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably getting an error like:

```
prog.c:10:14: error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'struct foo []'
  thing->foos[0][0].bar;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

For reference, the above is the output of compiling this code:

```c
struct foo { int bar; };
struct baz {
  struct foo (*foos)[];
};

int main () {
  struct baz * thing;
  thing->foos[0][0].bar;
  return 0;
}
```

[(Live)](http://ideone.com/v41JeV)

What the compiler is trying to tell you is that it cannot compute the offset needed to access subsequent elements of the outer array. The reason is that it doesn't know the size of the array elements (as they're of incomplete type, that is lacking size information).

Basically, it's trying to compute (the following is a pseudo language, not C)

```
thing + offset(foos) + 0 * sizeof(struct foo[]) + 0 * sizeof(struct foo) + offset(bar)
```

but it can't because it doesn't know `sizeof(struct foo[])`.

The root of this issue is that your trying to have a pointer to a variable length array in the first place. Changing the member to

```
struct foo (*foos)[42];
```

"solves" this by giving the arrays dome size.

If you want a 2D array just make it 1D, appending all inner arrays. (Of course this works only if they're of the same size, i.e. if you want a rectangular 2D array)

```
struct foo * grid = malloc (sizeof (struct foo) * rows * columns);
// access using grid [c * rows + r]
```

Comment: "The root of this issue is that your trying to have a pointer to a variable length array in the first place. " Okay so basically I'm using the width and height within the file to determine the dimensions of the array, which is then created in a method and I return the pointer to the array which looked like this COLOR (*colors)[width] = (COLOR(*)[width]) malloc(sizeof(COLOR[height][width])); , I then store it in COLOR (*colorValues)[];, so if I understand correctly because Im doing this im losing the [width] part of the LHS so it cant find the offset when im doing [x][y], then how do I ...cont

Comment: do I cast the color value that I access (newPPM->colorValues) to know it is size width offset? as it already has values stored in it?

Comment: I don't know if casting will help, as your width isn't compile time constant. Perhaps `COLOR(*)[width]` will work, but I'd stop going down that road and just use a single pointer. That's the best choice if you're trying to access one contiguous memory area.

Comment: thank you. One person told me to use a pointer to a 2D array, another a pointer to a 1d array, another a pointer to pointers and now Im down to the simplest answer, just use a pointer and I have changed all my code and it works fine. :)

Comment: Yes, keeping it simple is often the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can access 2D data in a 1D array by calculating the array index formula yourself.

```
buf[ width*y + x ];
```

where `width` needs to be the *stride* in units of the buffer type.